# Setting a script generated checkbox value as multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, submit

Hopefully someone can understand this...

I am still very new at php and I am stuck.

I have a question... 
I have a list with checkboxes that are generated by a foreach loop and each box should have a multidimensional array as it's value.

```
<input type='checkbox' name='unit[]' value='multidimensional array' />
```

I have a file containing the arrays like this:

```
$disclaimer = disclaimer;
$unit = array(
//EXTRAS
"0" => array("key0_key0" => "<h1>key0_key0_VALUE</h1>",
         "key0_key1" => "<li>key0_key1_VALUE</li>",
         "key0_key2" => "<li>key0_key2_VALUE</li>",
         "key0_key3" => "<li>key0_key3_VALUE</li>",
         "key0_key4" => "<li>key0_key4_VALUE</li>",                  
         "key0_key5" => "<li>key0_key_VALUE</li>",

         "key0_key6" => array("key0_key6_key1" => "<h1>key0_key6_key1_VALUE</h1>",
                              "key0_key6_key2" => "<li>key0_key6_key2_VALUE</li>"
                                                         ),
                                        ),
                  ),

//UNIT 1
"1" => array("key1_key0" => "<h1>key1_key0_VALUE</h1>",
         "key1_key1" => "<li>key1_key1_VALUE</li>",
         "key1_key2" => "<li>key1_key2_VALUE</li>",
         "key1_key3" => "<li>key1_key3_VALUE</li>",
         "key1_key4" => "<li>key1_key4_VALUE</li>",                  
         "key1_key5" => "<li>key1_key_VALUE</li>",

         "key1_key6" => array("key1_key6_key1" => "<h1>key1_key6_key1_VALUE</h1>",
                              "key1_key6_key2" => "<li>key1_key6_key2_VALUE</li>"
                                                         ),
                                        ),
                  ),    
//UNIT 2
"2" => array("key2_key0" => "<h1>key2_key0_VALUE</h1>",
         "key2_key1" => "<li>key2_key1_VALUE</li>",
         "key2_key2" => "<li>key2_key2_VALUE</li>",
         "key2_key3" => "<li>key2_key3_VALUE</li>",
         "key2_key4" => "<li>key2_key4_VALUE</li>",                  
         "key2_key5" => "<li>key2_key_VALUE</li>",

         "key2_key6" => array("key2_key6_key1" => "<h1>key2_key6_key1_VALUE</h1>",
                              "key2_key6_key2" => "<li>key2_key6_key2_VALUE</li>"
                                                         ),
                                        ),
);
```

I have these in a separate include file which I include where ever I might need these to be displayed.

then on my page I have this included followed by a foreach loop to display each with a checkbox that increments the checkbox value by one for each of the unit arrays.

```
$i = 0;

foreach($unit as $unit_no){
echo"<div class='pricelist-container'>";

if (is_array($unit_no)){

    foreach ($unit_no as $unit_details){

        if (is_array($unit_details)) {

            foreach ($unit_details as $unit_contents){

                if (is_array($unit_contents)){

                    foreach ($unit_contents as $extra){
                        echo $extra;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    echo $unit_contents;
                }
            }
        }

        else{
            echo $unit_details;
        }
    }
}
else{
    echo $unit_no;
}
echo"
$disclaimer
//below is where my problem seems to start.
<p class='fine'> <input type='checkbox' name='unit[]' value='" . "$" . "unit" . "[" . $i++ . "];' checked='checked' /> please uncheck to remove list</p>
<br />
</div>";
}
```

here is my problem as I have it... But as I am very new at this I might be horribly wrong.

I need these checkboxes to generate the $var[key] as a value and then after submitting the form it needs to be able to pass these variables to a new page where I have the array file included again so I can loop through the checked boxes and display them again on a shortlist. but I cannot have the code in such a way that I need to add little loops to echo out each one of these units every time one is added to the include file coz I will chang this include file to a database file and create an upload page for the site owner to create his/her own new units without having to edit anything for these to display on the site.

```
if(isset($_POST['unit'])){
            if (is_array($_POST['unit'])){
                foreach ($_POST['unit'] as $print_unit){
                    echo $print_unit;
                }
            }
        }
//this loop will echo out the $var[key] as strings.
```

the foreach above will echo out the $var as a string but not as a $var with incremented keys.

its basically a list of products with contents of each product in an array whith checkboxes to add or remove them from a printable list. Everything works except creating the checkbox values...

```
value='" . "$" . "unit" . "[" . $i++ . "];'
```

this will created the name $unit[1] for every array I have in the include but it generates a string $unit[1] but not as an actual array and it's first key.

Comment: change `value='" . "$" . "unit" . "[" . $i++ . "];'` to `value='" . $unit[$i++]."'`

Comment: Thanx @coramba. It passes array now :) 
Now all I need to figure out is the loop to echo it all again...

Comment: Okay then... 
So it passes array (tells me in source it's an array) but I cant echo the passed arrays out again for some reason?
It only echos the word "ARRAY".

CODE USED FOR ECHO

    if(isset($_POST['unit'])){
       if (is_array($_POST['unit'])){
          foreach ($_POST['unit'] as $print_unit){
             if (is_array($print_unit)){
                foreach ($print_unit as $P_unit){
                   echo $P_unit;
                }
             }
             else {
                echo "NOT ARRAY<br />";
             }
          }
       }
    }

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine helped me solve this problem and I am going to answer my own question as best I can with my limited knowledge.

It would be great if a PRO could just read this answer and confirm that it's OK.

ARRAY SETUP saved in an include file eg (data.php):

```
$Number = 1;

$unit[$Number]['id']="id";
$unit[$Number]['img']="image";
$unit[$Number]['name']="name";
$unit[$Number]['price']=00.00;
$unit[$Number]['contents'][1]="content1";
$unit[$Number]['contents'][2]="content2";
$unit[$Number]['contents'][3]="content3";
$unit[$Number]['contents'][4]="content4.";

$Number = 2;

$unit[$Number]['id']="id";
$unit[$Number]['img']="image";
$unit[$Number]['name']="name";
$unit[$Number]['price']=00.00;
$unit[$Number]['contents'][1]="content1";
$unit[$Number]['contents'][2]="content2";
$unit[$Number]['contents'][3]="content3";
$unit[$Number]['contents'][4]="content4.";

//END OF PRODUCT/UNIT ARRAYS
```

First List Display Loop to display a pricelist on the actual webpage:

After including your data file 
eg:

```
<!--OPEN FORM-->
<form method='post' action='SCRIPT FILE NAME.php'>

<?php 

  include('data.php'); 

  /*Set INCREMENT.*/
   $i = 1;

  /*DISPLAY LOOP*/
   foreach ($unit as $UNIT) 
   //ECHO SOME HTML FOR A LAYOUT CONTAINER DIV
     echo "<div class='####'>";
     //image
     echo "<img class='#' src='location_folder_details/".$UNIT['img']."'>";
     //name
     echo $UNIT['name'];
     //price
     echo "Dollar/Pound symbol".number_format ($UNIT['price'] , 2, '.' , ' ' );
     //contents

     //SECOND ARRAY LOOP FOR CONTENT
       if (is_array($UNIT['contents'])){
         foreach ($UNIT['contents'] as $unit_contents){
           echo "<li>".$unit_contents."</li>"; 
          }
        }
        else {
          echo "NO DETAILS AVAILABLE";
        }

     echo "<p class='fine' ><input type='checkbox' name='unit_$i' value='".$UNIT['id']."' checked='checked'> please uncheck to remove.</p>";
  //CLOSE HTML LAYOUT CONTAINER DIV.
   echo "</div>";
  //Increment $i
   $i ++;
  }
  //ADD HIDDEN FIELD TO REMEMBER INCREMENT 
   echo "<input type='hidden' name='count' value='$i'>";
?>

<!--ADD SUBMIT AND END FORM-->
 <input class='send' action='###.php' type='submit' name='NAME' value='SUBMIT'  />
 </form>
```

Then how to handle it

```
//ADD INCLUDE FILE 
include ('data.php');

//POST HIDDEN COUNT FIELD
$count = $_POST['count'];
//RE-SET INCREMENT 
$i = 1;

<?php    
  while ($i < $count){
    $var_name = "unit_$i";

  if (isset($_POST[$var_name])) {
    // The tickbox "value", is the UNIT ID... Check include.php
      $unit_id = $_POST["$var_name"];

  foreach ($unit as $UNIT) {
        if ($UNIT['id'] == $unit_id) {
      //HTML LAYOUT ECHO
           echo "<div class='####'>";
      //image
           echo "<img class='####' src='LOCATION/PATH/".$UNIT['img']."'>";
      //name
       echo $UNIT['name'];
      //price
        echo "DOLLAR/POND SYMBOL".number_format ($UNIT['price'] , 2, '.' , ' ' );

      //SECOND ARRAY LOOP FOR CONTENT
           if (is_array($UNIT['contents'])){
             foreach ($UNIT['contents'] as $unit_contents){
              //CONTENTS
               echo "<li>".$unit_contents."</li>"; 
                  }
           }
           else {
             echo "NO DETAILS AVAILABLE";
           }
           //HTML LAYOUT ECHO
             echo "</div>";
          }

        }
    }
    $i++;
  }
?>
```

I hope this becomes useful to other beginners coz I struggled with this for days and I could not figure it out.